# Fetch images across the internet with File API

Tags: 7, files

How can I use the FileAPI to fetch an image from another website via URL, and bring it into Drupal? Here is what I tried:

```
foreach ($data['photos'] as $item) {
            $photo = file_get_contents($item['url']);

            $filename = $entity->field_id['und'][0]['value'] . '-' . $x . '.jpg';

            $file = file_save_data($photo, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

            if (is_object($file) && file_exists($file->uri)) {
                $file->status = 1;
                $file = file_save($file);
                drupal_write_record('file_usage', $file);
                $entity->field_entity_image['und'][] = (array) $file;
                $x++;
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
```

It doesn't quite work. The first time around it grabs some of the photos, then the second time around, it should remove any photos in the system and resave them (even if none changed), I have no way to tell if the remote file is new or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try just leaving the remote files as remote and have something like http://drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper? There's an open issue in the module to add a field widget for image and file fields to support just a simple URL entry for a file.

Comment: How is that implemented? I see what it does, but not how to utilize it.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you are looking for, but I have used [Imagecache External](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external) with decent results.  Derivatives definitely gets saved locally.  I don't 100% recall whether a copy of the original gets saved locally.  This may or may not fit your needs.

The D7 version is in git, and not on the module page.

Comment: Interesting... so I would be able to use this with say Lightbox or jquery Cycle style display?

Comment: I suspect so.  Once in your templates, the images behave just like any other image field w/ an image style.  If you need it, you may need to make a no-scale image style so that a derivative gets saved locally, which isn't always a bad thing (allows you to set JPEG quality and ensure decent filesizes).

Comment: very interesting option. So the image styles get generated when you save your image node?

Comment: Derivative image URLs are built when the theme('image_style') gets invoked, and the img element via theme('image').  The actual derivative is generated on the fly when the URL is requested (see image_menu and image_style_deliver).  From the theme's and user's perspective, the external images are indistinguishable from other images using the same style when you use this module.